# How to find: $~\min\limits_{f\in E}(\int_0^1f(x) \,dx)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, contest-math

I came across to the following  problem:

> Let $E$ be the set of all continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x)+f(y)\ge |x-y|\qquad\forall\,x,y\in [0,1]$$
>
> Then find $$\min_{f\in E}\left(\int_0^1f(x) dx\right)$$

**My attempt:**
I took the double integral on both side which yields $$ 2\int_0^1f(x)dx =\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x) +f(y)dydx \ge \int_0^1\int_0^1|x-y|dxdy =\frac{1}{3} $$
Thus, 
$$~\min\limits_{f\in E}(\int_0^1f(x) \,dx) \ge \frac{1}{6}$$
Unfortunately I don't know How to get the minimizer. Please give help me with a hint or an answer.

Minimize $\min_{f\in E}\left(\int_0^1f(x) dx\right)$

Comment: Please try to limit your edits. While editing in general is appreciated, repeated minor edits can be perceived as noise.

Comment: I do not understand the point of your comment. If you want to imply that I have downvoted this question, please note, first, it is poor style to do this, second it is factually incorrect.

Comment: Out of curiosity where did you find this question? I'm sure I've seen it before. Might have been IMC.

Comment: @bwv869 you may be right but that was actually a problem I encountered with a friend. I did not ask him where he took it from. he wanted the challenge the groups after some lunch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Setting $y=1-x$, $f(x)+f(1-x)\geq |2x-1|$, and since $\int_0^1 f(1-x) dx =\int_0^1 f(x) dx$, integrate to get $$2\int_0^1 f(x)dx\geq \int_0^1 |2x-1| dx = \frac 12$$
hence $\int_0^1 f(x) dx \geq \frac 14$.

This bound is attained for $f:x\mapsto |x-\frac 12|$. The triangle inequality trivially yields $f(x)+f(y)\ge |x-y|$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx= \frac 14$

Comment: Ingenious +1 :)

Comment: Ingenius solution! +1

Comment: Would you care to check out a variation on this theme https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2514441/64809?